# Linq, Entity Framework and WCF

Tags: linq, wcf, entity-framework

If I have a customers and orders relationship in my Linq or EF model, at the WCF service layer I can add an order to the customer by calling

```
 Customer.Orders.Add(customer);
```

When I access my customer object on the client, and want to add an order, there is no Add method, and the Orders propery is an array. Is there any way I can work with my client side object, they same way as I do on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to be doing that, as the objects on the client have only a semantic similarity to the service's objects - *they are not the same types*.

This is done to conform to one of the important tenets of service-orientation: **Services share schema and contract, but not class**.

However, when you generate the client-side proxy, there are options where you can choose to have collections represented by `List<T>` instead of arrays.

Comment: That should do it, I can select this in the WCF configuration screen. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should look into [What is .NET RIA Services?](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2009/03/19/what-is-net-ria-services.aspx), [.NET RIA Services](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/RiaServices).

This describes, and provides tools for those scenarios